# xquery/xslt for selecting a value based on a specific value

Tags: xslt, xquery

I am stuck on an xquery for below request. I want to select the address based on the type value.
i.e. if type is "StreetAddress" then pick freeFormat "Maguire"

```
<associatedAddress>
    <address xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">
        <type xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">StreetAddress</type>
        <freeFormat xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">Maguire</freeFormat>
    </address>
    <address>
        <type xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">CityAddress</type>
        <freeFormat xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">SanFransisco</freeFormat>
    </address>
</associatedAddress>
```

I tried in couple of ways:
if `associatedAddress/address/type="StreetAddress"`
then.., But this one gives me only the first address

I also tried to use a for loop and then use if case inside it but even that gave me just the first address

Please let me know any other options. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The XPath for fetching value `Maguire` using the value in `<type>` is

```
<xsl:value-of select="associatedAddress/address[type='StreetAddress']/freeFormat" />
```

You need to take care of the `namespace` associated with the different elements in your input XML when fetching the value. If the namespace is not properly handled in the XSL, the value will not be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for xQuery given your input xml, this:

```
declare namespace common="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common";

for $n in associatedAddress//common:type[. = "StreetAddress"]
return 
  $n/../common:freeFormat
```

produces the desired result

```
<freeFormat xmlns="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common">Maguire</freeFormat>
```

The trick is that in your input xml associatedAddress is not in the same namespace as the other elements, so you need to adjust your query to take this into account.

You mention an if clause, but its is not clear what the desired output is from your question. You can use the below as a template to modify results.

```
declare namespace common="http://services.oracle.com/v1.0/Common";

 for $n in associatedAddress//common:type
 return 
     switch($n)
    case "StreetAddress" return $n/../common:freeFormat
    case "CityAddress"  return "something else"
    default 
        return ()
```